# Refresh PHP variable after user input

Tags: javascript, php

I have a very simple website   which helps me to calculate the end of day cash position in my store. Form is here: http://www.073design.nl/kasopmaak/kasopmaak.php#

But now I have to 'click' the "Calculate cash!" button to update the positions.

My questions now; is it possible to add some 'smart' extra code, which updates the totals directly after entering data per line?

Many thanks in advance.

Form uses only this code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST)) {

$total_100  = $_POST['100']  * 100     ;
$total_50   = $_POST['50' ]  *  50     ;
$total_20   = $_POST['20' ]  *  20     ; 
$total_10   = $_POST['10' ]  *  10     ;
$total_5    = $_POST['5'  ]  *   5     ;
$total_2    = $_POST['2'  ]  *   2     ;
$total_1    = $_POST['1'  ]  *   1     ;
$total_05   = $_POST['05' ]  *   0.5   ; 
$total_02   = $_POST['02' ]  *   0.2   ; 
$total_01   = $_POST['01' ]  *   0.1   ;
$total_005  = $_POST['005']  *   0.05  ;

$total = $total_100 + $total_50 + $total_20 + $total_10 + $total_5;  

} else {

$total_100  = 0  ;
$total_50   = 0  ;
$total_20   = 0  ; 
$total_10   = 0  ;
$total_5    = 0  ;
$total_2    = 0  ;
$total_1    = 0  ;
$total_05   = 0  ; 
$total_02   = 0  ;
$total_005  = 0  ;

$total = $total_100 + $total_50 + $total_20 + $total_10 + $total_5 + $total_2 +  $total_1 +  $total_05 +  $total_02 +  $total_01 +  $total_005 ;  

}

?>


<body>

<h1>kas opmaak</h1>

<form action="#" method="POST">
<table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="number" name="100" value="<?php echo $_POST['100']; ?>"></td>
                <td>X</td>
                <td>&#8364; 100</td>
                <td> = </td>
                <td align="right"><?php echo $total_100;?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="number" name="50"  value="<?php echo $_POST['50'];?>"></td>
                <td>X</td>
                <td>&#8364; 50</td>
                <td> = </td>
                <td align="right"><?php echo $total_50;?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="number" name="20"  value="<?php echo $_POST['20'];?>"></td>
                <td>X</td>
                <td>&#8364; 20</td>
                <td> = </td>
                <td align="right"><?php echo $total_20;?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="number"  name="10" value="<?php echo $_POST['10'];?>"></td>
                <td>X</td>
                <td>&#8364; 10</td>
                <td> = </td>
                <td align="right"><?php echo $total_10;?></td>
            </tr>           
            <tr>
                <td><input type="number"  name="5"  value="<?php echo $_POST['5'];?>"></td>
                <td>X</td>
                <td>&#8364; 5</td>
                <td> = </td>
                <td align="right"><?php echo $total_5;?></td>
            </tr>
<tr>
                <td><input type="number"  name="2"  value="<?php echo $_POST['2'];?>"></td>
                <td>X</td>
                <td>&#8364; 2</td>
                <td> = </td>
                <td align="right"><?php echo $total_2;?></td>
            </tr>
<tr>
                <td><input type="number"  name="1"  value="<?php echo $_POST['1'];?>"></td>
                <td>X</td>
                <td>&#8364; 1</td>
                <td> = </td>
                <td align="right"><?php echo $total_1;?></td>
            </tr>
<tr>
                <td><input type="number"  name="05"  value="<?php echo $_POST['05'];?>"></td>
                <td>X</td>
                <td>&#8364; 0,50</td>
                <td> = </td>
                <td align="right"><?php echo $total_05;?></td>
            </tr>
<tr>
                <td><input type="number"  name="02"  value="<?php echo $_POST['02'];?>"></td>
                <td>X</td>
                <td>&#8364; 0,20</td>
                <td> = </td>
                <td align="right"><?php echo $total_02;?></td>
            </tr>
<tr>
                <td><input type="number"  name="01"  value="<?php echo $_POST['01'];?>"></td>
                <td>X</td>
                <td>&#8364; 0,10</td>
                <td> = </td>
                <td align="right"><?php echo $total_01;?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="number"  name="005"  value="<?php echo $_POST['005'];?>"></td>
                <td>X</td>
                <td>&#8364; 0,05</td>
                <td> = </td>
                <td align="right"><?php echo $total_005;?></td>
            </tr>           
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><strong> Totaal contant </strong></td>

                <td><?php echo $total;?></td>
            </tr>               








            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" align="right"><br/>  <input type="submit" value="Calculate cash!"></td>

            </tr>

</table>        
</form>
```

Comment: was that you wanted ?

Comment: No, not exactly. I want that after someone enters for example '10' at EUR 50,- directly the line is updatet with 10 x 50 = 500. So you don't have to push enter meanwhile you're filling out the form

Comment: u need ajax for that , i dont know much of it may someone else will help you

Comment: Thanks Wasim! Fingers crossed for the next helping hand. Enjoy your weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is relatively easy to do this using jquery. I wrote for you a sample code by implement only your first formula `[   ] X 100 = [ ]`. It can be very easy adapted to cover all your formulas.

When the user enters a number the formula is automatically calculated. It also works with the `backspace` or `delete` when the user deletes a number.... 
Please note that for the case simplicity I avoided to use any error-exception handling code.
It also works without the need of server... ;)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
i = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){  
   $("#in100").keyup(function(){
      $('#out100').get(0).value = $('#in100').get(0).value * 100;
    });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="in100" /> X 100 = <input type="text" id="out100" readonly="true" value=""/>


</body>
</html>
```